next-auth redirect returns /api/auth/error?error=Configuration
I'm using nextjs 14 and next-auth, there is a function in middleware.ts called withAuth that redirects the user to /signin if he is not logged in, this works perfectly on localhost redirecting the user to http://localhost:3000/signin?callbackUrl=%2Fcheckout, but when deploying to vercel, and accessing /checkout, the url becomes https://my-app.vercel.app/api/auth/error?error=Configuration.
Note: The common login function works.
I tried modifying the NEXTAUTH_URL and NEXTAUTH_SECRET environment variables, with no result.
I checked the urls in GPC, and they are correct http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google and https://my-app.vercel.app/api/auth/callback/Google. The problem persists.

I had encountered the same issue, I added redirectTo param into signout function and worked, not sure if it's worked for you.
